# Dynamic type cast from id to class in objective c

Tags: objective-c, dynamic-typing

I would like to cast dynamically in Objective C and access instance properties. Here a pseudo code:

```
id obj;
if (condition1)
    obj = (Class1*)[_fetchedResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
else
    obj = (Class2*)[_fetchedResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSNumber *latitude = obj.latitude;
```

Then the compiler tells me the following:
*property 'latitude' not found on object of type '__strong id'*

Either Class1 and Class2 are core data entities and have nearly the same kind of attributes. In condition1 *_fetchedResults* returns objects of type Class1 and in condition2 *_fetchedResults* returns objects of type Class2.

Could someone give me a hint how to solve this kind of problem?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you should make sure firstly that what [_fetchedResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] returns is the Class has the latitude property. Also, casting a none NSManagedObject type to a NSManagedObject type is wrong either. You need a NSManagedObjectContext whenever and however you create a NSManagedObject instance.

Answer (score 7):

You can access the properties through Key-Value Coding (KVC):

```
[obj valueForKey:@"latitude"]
```

Comment: Note that using KVC to do this robs you of any type-checking from the compiler.

Comment: @ipmcc Sure, but so does using `id` in the first place :-)

Comment: @Monolo This is unnecessary and has the same effect as [obj latitude]

Comment: @hooleyhoop True. I'd venture that using KVC conveys intention slightly better, but that is a matter of coding style. The error messages you'd get (at runtime, alas) are also quite different. And you might in theory have defined a getter with a different name if we want to cover that one, too.

Comment: Key-Value coding is documented practice for managed objects, so the only thing I would change is to replace `id` by `NSManagedObject *`.

Answer (score 3):

The `obj` variable needs to be of a type that has the property in question. If both entities have the same property, one way to achieve this would be for the property to be declared on a common base class. If it's not appropriate for these two types to share a common base class, then you could have them adopt a common protocol, like this:

```
@protocol LatitudeHaving
@property (copy) NSNumber* latitude;
@end

@interface Class1 (AdoptLatitudeHaving) <LatitudeHaving>
@end

@interface Class2 (AdoptLatitudeHaving) <LatitudeHaving>
@end
```

From there, you would declare `obj` as being an `id<LatitutdeHaving>`, like this:

```
id<LatitudeHaving> obj;
if (condition1)
    obj = (Class1*)[_fetchedResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
else
    obj = (Class2*)[_fetchedResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSNumber *latitude = obj.latitude;
```

And that should do it. FWIW, protocols are similar to Interfaces in Java.

Comment: what are the Class1* and Class2* casts for?

Comment: `objectAtIndex:` returns an `id` not an `id<LatitudeHaving>`. Those casts may not be strictly necessary to avoid compiler complaints, but I was trying to make the code as close to the OP's code as possible.